# How do I define multiple OnInit events on the same page in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page in which I create dynamic controls via OnInit. On the page I also have a custom user control in which i want to create other dynamic controls via OnInit (defined with override). The event in the user control overrides the event on the page: how do i prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you calling base.OnInit() in your override?